# Numpy - Try to split an array according to a monotonic condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that is a sequence of (x, y) coordinates. I'm trying to split it according to a monotonic condition. To exemplify this:

```
cords = np.array([[1,1],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[4,3],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[5,7],[5,5]])
```

I would like split the array and make sure for each sub array x is monotonic (appear once). The results should be:

```
cord1 = np.array([[1,1],[2,3],[4,3],[5,7])
cord2 = np.array([[2,4],[4,5],[5,5])
cord3 = np.array([[2,5],[4,6]])
cord4 = np.array([[4,7]])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @tangoman, what is the purpose of this: what do you need it for?

Comment: give us an example of monotonic condition you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this iteratively by extracting monotonic coordinates progressively from the remainder of your array:

```
import numpy as np

cords = np.array([[1,1],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[4,3],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[5,7],[5,5]])

result = []
while cords.size>0:
    mask = np.insert(cords[:-1,0] != cords[1:,0],0,[True])
    result.append(cords[mask,:])
    cords = cords[mask==False,:]
```

Output:

```
for mono in result: print(list(map(list,mono)))

[[1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 3], [5, 7]]
[[2, 4], [4, 5], [5, 5]]
[[2, 5], [4, 6]]
[[4, 7]]
```

note: this assumes that the points are in order of their x coordinate. You will need to sort them beforehand if that is not the case.